# iPad slidable panel control like twitter

Tags: ipad, user-interface, twitter, panel, slide

What would be the mechanism behind twitter iPad application? I feel its having split viewcontroller, viewcontrollers with animation and gesture controls, or there may be scrollviews for endless scrolling.
How can I develop same UI for my application?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hey, here our is a demo project which is inspired by Twitter-ipad app

> http://www.raweng.com/blog/stack-scroll-view/

its source code is opensource on githib (link posted in above blog).

hope that help u to understand the concept behind it !!

Comment: Yep, that's a great one, I'm glad you mentioned it because I was returning to update my answer to redirect to your work.  There's a few good forks of the project too.  There's one in particular that adds icons to the cells/"tabs".  Right now, I'm trying to work out how to build in persistence of the view hierarchy.

Comment: @Martin i guess site is under maintenance.

anyways you can go directly to github link here https://github.com/raweng/StackScrollView/

Answer (score 2):

Matt Gammell ... He did a draggable split view.  Its the closest i can think of  may be configurable to emulate that  http://github.com/mattgemmell/MGSplitViewController

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is just a scroll view with enabled paging, that moves it's subviews on `scrollViewDidScroll`, does some additional animation in `scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation` method and with some other slick and sexy things :)